# Accelerated computing: GeForce RTX vs. Quardo RTX

Tags: laptop, graphics-cards

I want to do atomic simulation of proteins using CUDA.

I am preparing to purchase a Lenovo laptop. The available GPU options are: the GeForce RTX 4070 and Quadro RTX 5000.

Which one would be better for my purpose and why?

Wherever I see any benchmark, I see that GeForce outperforms Quadro by miles. If that is so, why is Quardro even in the market?

Comment: This question has been answered already. But then you deleted the question and now you've asked it again. You will get the same answer.

Comment: @Gantendo, Then, please refrain from posting an answer.

Comment: No, if a question has been answered you should refrain from reposting it.

Comment: @Gantendo, There was no answer. You posted a bunch or comments.

Comment: Those comments contained the answers to the questions. As you are well aware.

Comment: @Gantendo, No they didn't. I asked for a comparison between two GPUs in a Lenovo laptop. You told me to discard laptops and use a desktops.

Comment: I also told you to look up when the GPUs were made. You really think a very old GPU is somehow better? Using a desktop instead of a laptop for tasks like this is great advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, Quadro RTX is based on Turing, and the RTX 4070 is based on the Ada architecture. Turing is way older (it was used in the RTX 2080 for example) so that's why the 4070 is faster. That doesn't mean Quadro is useless, there are Ampere based Quadro cards (like the RTX A6000) and those are faster than the Geforce 4070 in some use cases (like the ones that require 40GB of RAM) so there is still a use case for Quadro cards, you are just comparing Turing to Ada, and Ada will AFAIK always win